# Writing if..else construct without long condition checks to increase maintainability

Tags: c#, comparative-review

Should writing if..else construct in the following manner be flagged for correction in peer code review?

**Existing Code**

```
bool userInstanceHasTransactions = userInstance != null && userInstance.Transactions > 0;
if(userInstanceHasTransactions) {
   //Processing logic here
} else {
  //Some other processing here
}
```

**Flagged to change as**

```
if(userInstance != null && userInstance.Transactions > 0) {
   //Processing logic here
} else {
  //Some other processing here
}
```

I have observed code of this kind in C#, but I believe language really does not mattter for this question.

I noticed there are lot of if..else construct written in this manner. Will too many if..else construct in this manner impact size of the binary file (dll or exe)?

Is it correct to say writing if..else construct in the manner depicted above increases readability?

Comment: On Code Review, we review real code, not generic practices or sketchy situations. Please fill in the contextual information so that we can see what this code is really doing. (See [ask].)

Comment: Also retitle the question according to the [ask] guidelines. As a rule, if the title is asking about a practice rather than stating the task performed by the code, then the question is off-topic.

Comment: @200_success this is not a hypothetical question nor the code is pseudocode. It is an existing code which was reviewed. I have pasted relevant code sections only which triggered my question. I have edited the title. Let me know if this is still Off topic?

Comment: The title is still mainly about a concern or a practice, rather than about what the ode accomplishes. Therefore, the code is still too generic or sketchy to be on-topic for Code Review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Replace Temp variables with queries

It's a primary refactoring technique championed by Fowler in his book Refactoring. That as well as the second technique of extracting methods from complex/long code dramatically improves code readability. Please see below for examples:

```
public void Testc()
{            
    // The code that you've suggested as the first option
    // makes the if statement more readable and it should be preserved
    // over the complicated code within the if statement IMO: i.e. if(userInstance != null && userInstance.Transactions > 0)
    // but it introduces the problem of temporary variables - which, when refactoring
    // should probably be replaced with a query, as Martin Fowler suggests,
    // unless you have cogent reasons to preserve them as a temporary variables 
    // (i.e. for performance reasons). If that's the case, Fowler suggests
    // to still replace the temporary variable with a query, and further down the line
    // to THEN start thinking about optimisation. This might force you back to using temporary
    // variables.

    // Summary:
    // So Fowler suggests to replace the logic with a query. And Then to
    // start thinking about optimisation if required
    // so it would look something like this:

    if (UserInstanceHasTransactions())
    {
        //Processing logic here
    }
    else
    {
        //Some other processing here
    }
}

public bool UserInstanceHasTransactions()
{
    return userInstance != null && userInstance.Transactions > 0;
}
```

As Volundi points out sometimes the userInstance might itself be a temporary variable. if that's the case you might have to do something like this:

```
public bool UserInstanceHasTransactions(userInstance )
{
    return userInstance != null && userInstance.Transactions > 0;
}
```

And you could call it like this:

```
if (UserInstanceHasTransactions(userInstance))
{
    //Processing logic here
}
else
{
    //Some other processing here
}
```

Above all the important thing is to preserve readability, because your code will be read many more times than it is edited. If the userInstance is a temporary variable then you might want to consider refactoring all those instances as a query method and as Fowler suggests, if performance is not a problem.

Comment: It seems like this suggestion makes the implicit assumption that `userInstance` is a member of the class at hand and therefore visible from inside other methods. If this is not the case I suggest, you write the more complex if but split it into multiple lines like...

`if(userInstance != null //newline goes here`                                   

 `&& userInstance.Transactions > 0) {`

(the comment is just there to show the intended formatting)

Comment: @vonludi thx for the comment have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> I have observed code of this kind in C#, but I believe language really does not mattter for this question.

You're right, C# does not care but **people do**. You add the helper variable to explain the condition so that **you** still know in four weeks what the condition means.

As far as C# is concerned you don't need any line breaks eaither and you can write your code in a single line.

```
if(userInstance != null && userInstance.Transactions > 0) { /* Processing logic here */ } else { /* Some other processing here */ }
```

The code is not only for the compiler. People need to read it and they need to know what it does (not only today but in a month too) so yes, a lengthy condition inside an `if` is a bad thing.

Comment: The point @t3chb0t makes about readability is good advice and very sound. I wholeheartedly concur: people read code not machines.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon sometimes not even Fowler can help you until you had the experience youself and find later that you wonder how the _damn_ thing works that you wrote a few weeks ago :-) I find _rules_ or _priciples_ make only sense if you know why they actually exist. Fowler speaks about readability but I think he does not emphasize it strongly enough.

Comment: Agreed @t3chb0t on **People read code**.